# 8086Assembly - Unable to Reverse String

Tags: assembly, x86-16, microprocessors, emu8086

```
JMP START
MSG1 DB "ISSK$"
MSG2 DB 80 DUP("$")
START:

MOV SI,00H
MOV DI,00H

LOOPER:          
CMP MSG1[DI],"$"
JE COMPARE
INC DI
JMP LOOPER  ;AFTER THIS POINT DI=STRINGLENGTH-1


COMPARE:
MOV AL,MSG1[DI]
MOV MSG2[SI],AL
INC SI
DEC DI
CMP MSG1[DI],00H
JE OUTER
JMP COMPARE

OUTER:
MOV DX,OFFSET MSG2
MOV AH,09H
INT 21H
HLT
```

The console of my EMULATOR(emu8086) finally prints a Blank Screen instead of the Reversed string. Where did I go wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you exit `LOOPER` and go to `COMPARE`, `DI` contains the index of the `'$'` terminator character, which you then place at the start of `MSG2`. You should decrement `DI` before entering the `COMPARE` loop so that it contains the index of `'K'`.

Then you've got `CMP MSG1[DI],00H` which doesn't make any sense. I suspect that you wanted to check if `DI == 0`. If so, this entire part:

```
DEC DI
CMP MSG1[DI],00H
JE OUTER
JMP COMPARE
```

could be replaced by:

```
DEC DI
JNZ COMPARE  ; continue the COMPARE loop as long as DI != 0
```